# It it possible let Navigationtroller not to display full screen?

Tags: iphone

I have an UIView (320*300 the view of an UIViewController), I hope to display UINaviationCotroller and control the navigation within this view size.

Is it possible?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you'll find out a snippet of code that does it. But let me give you a word of wisdom. **Don't do it**. Avoid at all costs. Apple doesn't recommend doing that. You will have nightmares and will be busy patching edge cases. It worked well in 3.x, with iOS 4 you'll have to work around a lot of special cases.

```
- (void) _adjustViewControllerforTicker {
 TickerView* vv = [ApplicationContext getTickerView];
if ([PreferenceDataModel isTickerOn]&& self.navigationController.view.frame.origin.y==0) {

    CGRect tableRect = self.tableView.frame;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableRect.origin.x,tableRect.origin.y, tableRect.size.width, tableRect.size.height -20);
    UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
    CGRect gframe = CGRectOffset(self.navigationController.view.frame, 0, 20);
    self.navigationController.view.frame = gframe;
    if (!vv) {
        vv = [[TickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 20)];

        [nav.view addSubview:vv];
        [vv release];
        self.tableView.contentInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,20.0,0.0);
    }
}   
if (![PreferenceDataModel isTickerOn]) {
    self.tableView.contentInset= UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    if (vv){
        [vv removeFromSuperview];
        vv=nil;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

yes.. why do you think it wouldn't be? It is probably non-standard but technically it can be done

Comment: UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
               initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
navController=navigationController;
navController.navigationItem.title = @"abc";
 
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];

Comment: above are my codes. myViewcontroler.view size is 320*300, but unfortunately, navController still appeared as full screen